# angularjs - routes not working when typed

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

Could anyone explain why when I click on a link my angular views get shown fine but when I type in an address into the address bar in the browser (which is the same as where the links that work point to) such as **localhost:8080/login** I get a **Cannot GET /login** message.

My routes are set up in Angular and I'm using Node and Express 3 on the back-end.

What silly mistake am I making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you're getting angular and your webserver mixed up.

The webserver probably doesn't know to server your angular base page when the /login URL is entered.  You need a catch-all handler on your nodejs server.

Comment: thanks for that - I was messing around with my `server.js` file and I removed a key line to do with the routes - I will tick when I can